# Using "=TRANSPOSE()" for my column headers, how do I keep data linked when I insert a new row in the original data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one sheet which is my data in which I list my events and their dates. These are then inserted on a separate sheet where volunteers can use checkboxes for their availability. Now if I reorder my events in the data-sheet then the headers in the availability sheet will move, but the availability will not move with them. Any way to fix this?

Here is an example sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tTVMOCKnLT2dRhKDBMV74LNMYOQvxKv3AA8egHCVG78/edit?usp=sharing

This is a simplified example from my actual problem, but I was wondering if there is a good way to keep this data linked? I would like to be able to re-order the data in the "Events Data" sheet while keeping the correct availability under each event in the "Availability sheet". Currently, one moves and the other one is static.

Comment: Can you please provide access to your sheet?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have updated the link in my original post as well.

Comment: Do you reorder by changing the rows order or by changing the data?

Comment: What would probably happen in the real case is that someone will add a new row between two existing ones, thus shifting all the header data. I wonder if there is a way to prevent that shifting.

Comment: The sheet is now in your trash. Did you solve your problem or made another one? You may want to update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I've done this using Google Apps Script in a similar situation (in my case, associating a "memo" column with rows producted by `QUERY`). Essentially, what we do is synthesize our dynamic display (with `QUERY` in my case and `TRANSPOSE` in yours) from static sources (other sheets), and use Google Apps Script to move data entered on the dynamic sheet to the appropriate static sheet, where we can easily retrieve it and render it appropriately.

The only information stored on the dynamic sheet is that used for rendering it (`TRANSPOSE`, `VLOOKUP`, whatever works for your situation). When the user edits that sheet, we will take the value of their edit and immediately move it to a static sheet using `onEdit()`. This information from the static sheet will then be rendered onto the dynamic sheet, regardless of how its rendering changes.

First, create a sheet where you will store the true values for each row.

Second, use an `arrayformula` `vlookup` (or `hlookup`) to search your storage sheet based on a unique identifier from your transposed sheet, e.g.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Storage!A2:B, 2, 0), ""))`

Third, using the Script Editor, add the following to your `onEdit()` function in Google Apps Script:

```
if (/* use e.range here to check that you're in an appropriate location... */) {
//this section should execute on our 'dynamic' sheet, after the user edits it
      var unique_id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
// the 'getRange' here is looking from where the user edited to a unique identifier
// associated with this record; this could potentially be built on to reference multiple unique identifiers.
// For instance, this would be the cell with the text, e.g., unique_id = 'Event A'
// and the script could be extended to ALSO pick up, e.g. "edited_person", etc.

      var storagesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Storage');
      var findid = storagesheet.createTextFinder(unique_id).findNext();
// this will search your storage sheet to see if there is an existing entry associated with the unique ID
      if (findid) {
        storagesheet.getRange(findid.getRow(), 2, 1, 2).setValues([[e.value, e.user]]);
// if there is, then we update it ON THE STORAGE SHEET with the new contents of the cell
      } else {
        storagesheet.appendRow([unique_id, e.value, e.user]);
// otherwise, we create one with the contents of the cell. 
//This can likewise be expanded; create more cells, update more sheets, create new sheets, whatever else may be needed
      }
      e.range.clearContent();
      if (e.range.getRow() === 2) { //or wherever your array formula is, again we are assuming this part of the onEdit() should only occur for edits of the dynamic sheet
        //making sure we don't lose array formula if the user writes in this field
        e.range.setFormula("=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Storage!A2:B, 2, 0), \"\"))")
      }
}
```

These are based on vertically stored/displayed information, and only store a single field for each unique ID, but you can extrapolate on that pretty easily to match based on both the event and person's value, store multiple values for each event, etc. according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am not sure I fully understand, at what time will the function onEdit() populate my storage sheet? Will it populate it before the changes of the edit? Otherwise I feel like it will store the already shifted data..

Comment: For more detailed information on `onEdit()`, see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) -- but essentially, after the user fills in or changes any field, it will run. That is what the if-statement is for--to ensure that we are on the correct sheet, and that `e.range` is in the range of rows/columns we want to interact with, otherwise it will simply return

Comment: Coming back because I realized what you meant--you misunderstand. We are not saving when the user inputs a new row to the event list, but when the user changes the information on our display page. Again, think of one dynamic sheet (our 'dashboard', with the list of users and events), and multiple static sheets (one for users, one for events, etc.) -- when the user information is edited on the dynamic sheet, what we do is take that information and save it to one of the static sheets. All the dynamic sheet actually contains is what is needed to render it (the `TRANSPOSE` and `VLOOKUP`)

Comment: @lazergem I've expanded on my answer a little bit to help clarify how this is set up and how it works. Please give it a second reading and see if that clears it up.

Comment: your users never change more than a row at once? for checkbox it's easy to do, but the e.value only work if the e.range is only one cell.

Comment: In my case, yes. If it were absolutely vital to support changes via pasting across a range, I imagine it could probably be done by `flush()`ing, reading from the spreadsheet contents, and then using that instead of `e.value`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I missed the part with `e.range.clearContent();`, I will try it out tonight, but I think this will solve my problem. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @sinaraheneba I'm not sure how flush() would help? because the onEdit() script would still get triggered after a range has been changed and it's just making sure ''all pending changes are made right away''. So how do you lnow where to read from the spreadsheet content?

Comment: @sinaraheneba tested and flush() allows to use first value in range but won't change the others. Also, with this setup the checkbox values can't be easily changed. Works for dropdown menu tho.

Comment: Like I said, `flush()` followed by reading the **sheet's** contents, not the contents of `e.value`. You *wouldn't* know where to read from (unless you can get a hint from `e.range`), thus needing to read whatever parts of the sheet you want to monitor for changes (e.g., an entire column or row).

Comment: Oh, okay, but you already just do that without flush. Like you don't need flush to get the data, but you might want it so the person see the edits live since value are looked for one at a time.